# Checking .Net Session class returning null while session exists....

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a Session class in my .net application, when the user authenticates (using forms auth) i set some other session data using the below class

```
 Friend NotInheritable Class MySession
    Private Const EIDKey As String = "EID"

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Private Shared ReadOnly Property Session As HttpSessionState
        Get
            Return HttpContext.Current.Session
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Exists() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Not Session Is Nothing
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Property EID As Integer
        Get
            Return DirectCast(Session(EIDKey), Integer)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Session(EIDKey) = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

However, in some page logic i will do a check to direct back to a signin page

```
  If IsNothing(Users.MySession.Exists) or Users.MySession.Exists = False Then Response.Redirect("/user/login")
    If IsNothing(Users.MySession.EID) Then Response.Redirect("/user/login/")
```

But in some cases exists will return true, and EID throws a null reference. I think this happens perhaps when a session breaks? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to check? Do you want to check if user is signed in or not?

Comment: Well, I'm using forms auth in combination with some session variables. If the session timeout is set to the same duration as forms auth, shouldn't this condition never occur? I cant find out why forms auth thinks they are logged in, but their session data is done.